# Spring is encoding incorrectly

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getCategoryAspectValues", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> retrieveCategoryAspectValues(@RequestParam long cat, @RequestParam String aspectName) {
        return new GetAspectsTask().getAspectValues(cat, (StringUtils.encodeAspectName(aspectName)));       
    }
```

When the Request URL:http://localhost:8080/rpt/getCatValues?cat=55793&aName=US+Shoe+Size+(Women%27s) is as following, the decoded aspectName value is "US Show Size (Women s)" instead of "US Show Size (Women's)". It would be helpful if the reason for incorrect encoding is provided.

Comment: Exactly which StringUtils class are you using? Please provide its fully qualified name.

Comment: I would like to mention here that the return value I am getting is perfectly right but the parameters are getting populated incorrectly

Comment: my primary question is that will requestparam correctly decode percent encoding as " ' " will be sent as %27